# mongodb bulk find and remove operation in php

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, jenssegers-mongodb

As I wanted to delete a collection that consists approx 50M data(monthly), the normal delete operation was throwing a timeout error even after declaring timeout to -1.
the query I am using is `$this->where('ts', '>', $start)->where('ts', '<' , $end)->timeout(-1)->delete()`.
I found `bulk.find().remove()` operation on mongodb doc which could help but I am unable to find `find()` method in any of the mongo drivers of php.
any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "find and delete" operation in MongoDB. This is simply  a conditional delete.

For an example using the PHP driver, [try this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/blob/master/tests/bulk/write-0001.phpt) where the `$bulk->delete()` call is made.